# Return a list from within a function

Tags: python, list, return

I'm trying to call a list I created within a function in another function, but I get the error that the list is not defined. When I tried to do Menu = The_menu(), it runs the while loop within the function. The problem occurs when I call Restaurant_str

```
from collections import namedtuple
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone menu')
Dish = namedtuple("Dish", "name price calories")


# Constructor:   r1 = Restaurant('Taillevent', 'French', '01-11-22-33-44',  'Escargots', 23.50)

def Restaurant_str(self: Restaurant) -> str:
    return (
        "Name:     " + self.name + "\n" +
        "Cuisine:  " + self.cuisine + "\n" +
        "Phone:    " + self.phone + "\n" +
        "Menu:  " + Dishlist_display(Menu))

def Restaurant_get_info() -> Restaurant:
    """ Prompt user for fields of Restaurant; create and return.
    """
    return Restaurant(
        input("Please enter the restaurant's name:  "),
        input("Please enter the kind of food served:  "),
        input("Please enter the phone number:  "), The_menu())

def The_menu():
    """ Creates the menu that replaces dish in Restaurant.
    """
    Menu = []
    while True:
        x = input("Please enter the name of a Dish:  ")
        if x == "No more":
            break
        y = float(input("Please enter the price of that Dish:  "))
        z = float(input("Please enter the calorie count of that Dish:  "))
        Menu.append(Dish(x, y, z))
    return Menu


def Dish_str(x:Dish) -> str:
    """ Takes a Dish and returns a string with name, price, and calories   listed.
    """
    return (x.name + " ($" + str(x.price) + "): " + str(x.calories) + " cal")

def Dishlist_display(x:list) -> str:
    """Takes a list of Dishes and returns one large string consisting of the     string representation of each dish followed by a newline character
    """
    dish = ""
    for i in x:
         dish = dish + Dish_str(i) + ("\n")
    return dish
```

Here's the traceback,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jayjay\Documents\ICS 31\Lab 5\restaurantsd.py", line 193,      in <module>
restaurants()
  File "C:\Users\jayjay\Documents\ICS 31\Lab 5\restaurantsd.py", line 15, in  restaurants
    our_rests = handle_commands(our_rests)
  File "C:\Users\jayjay\Documents\ICS 31\Lab 5\restaurantsd.py", line 43, in   handle_commands
    print(Collection_str(C))
  File "C:\Users\jayjay\Documents\ICS 31\Lab 5\restaurantsd.py", line 128,   in Collection_str
    s = s + Restaurant_str(r)
  File "C:\Users\jayjay\Documents\ICS 31\Lab 5\restaurantsd.py", line 76, in   Restaurant_str
    "Menu:  " + Dishlist_display(Menu))
NameError: name 'Menu' is not defined
```

Comment: You should tag the programming language. This looks like Python?

Comment: Could you please copy and paste the actual traceback?

Comment: Can you provide the code for Dish also?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code. And when I run it (with a simplenamespace `Dish` class) in Python 3.4, it works.

Comment: Where are you doing `Dishlist_display(Menu)`? If it's outside this function, it can't access this function's local variable `Menu`. But since you did a `return Menu`, then presumably you stored it somewhere, and can access it from that somewhere.

Comment: At any rate, the code that's actually _wrong_ is the code that calls this function and `Dishlist_display`, not this function, so that's the code that you have to show us if you want it debugged.

Comment: The `NameError` means you're probably not defining the variable `Menu`.  Are you calling `Menu = The_Menu()` before you call `Dishlist_display(Menu)` (or even `Dishlist_display(The_Menu())`)?  Based on your error, it sounds as if that may be your issue.

Comment: You need to add in more code, specifically always include the code around and including the line on which the error occurred. Otherwise there is no way for us to see what is wrong.

Comment: This is very bizarre code. Why are you trying to fake a `Restaurant` class around a `Restaurant` record and a bunch of functions? If you're trying to learn how to implement OO yourself from scratch, you're missing the closure, which is a crucial element. If you're not, why not just use a `class Restaurant` and make all these things methods?

Comment: Please read [Python 3 tutorial chapter 9. *Classes*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're calling `Dishlist_display(Menu)` from inside `Restaurant_str`, but you don't have a variable named `Menu` in that function.

The fact that you happen to have a local variable of that name in another function doesn't do you any good. Once that other function returned, that variable disappeared.

What you need to do is either take the value returned from `The_menu` and pass it along the chain from one function to the next, or stash it somewhere that everyone who needs it can find it.

If you wrote this in normal OO style, the right thing to do would be to stash it in an attribute of the `Restaurant` instance that these functions would all be members of. If you really want to write in (non-OCa)ML fake-OO style ported clumsily to Python as you seem to be doing, the right thing to do is stash it in a nonlocal variable in the closure that represents the object. If you want a pure functional style, then the right thing to do is to pass it along from function to function. But you have to do *something* to get the value returned by `The_menu` into something that `Restaurant_str` can access.

Comment: okay thanks, I see that I made this more complicated that it should've been. I'll do it like you said

Comment: Let me reiterate a point here - this would be much better if it were object oriented.

Comment: @Joel: Actually, I suspect you could design this app without OO. It's more that if you _do_ design it in OO terms, then you should use Python's OO features instead of trying to do it from scratch. Once you start throwing in `self` args outside of methods, it's time to back up and ask why they're not methods.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to reference an unknown variable  "Menu"  instead of calling the function that builds the menu.

```
"Menu:  " + Dishlist_display(Menu))
```

should read

```
"Menu:  " + Dishlist_display(The_menu()))
```

Alternatively, you can create the variable you're trying to reference by using Menu = The_menu()